# How to find and show files in one command?

Tags: linux, bash

I have to find all files (in `~/`), which weren't moderated more than 14 days and show content of files, which ends on `*.txt`. I have tried to do something like this:

```
find ~/ -mtime +14 | cat '*.txt'
```

But it ignores everything before `|`. Can you help me?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971441/unix-system-comand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only `*.txt` files filter it with -name of [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), to cat those files simply add -exec

```
 find ~/ -mtime +14 -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your line

```
find ~/ -mtime +14 | cat '.txt'
```

the `find` would print the filenames, which are piped to `cat`'s `stdin`, where they are ignored, and `cat` would print the contents of the file `.txt`, which probably doesn't exist.

So, Try this:

```
find ~/ -mtime +14 -exec cat {} \;
```

where `-exec .... \;` executes the `....` command, and `{}` is replaced by the filename that `find` found.

Or you could use `xargs`:

```
find ~/ -mtime +14 -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

The `-print0` argument to `find` will print the filename followed by a null character, and the `-0` argument to `xargs` tells it that the input is separated by a null character, so that there won't be any problems with filenames that contain spaces in them.

Comment: @Biffen Indeed - Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is good and all, but it's missing the `.txt` bit.